# decrypt data using master key and not key used for encryption

Tags: security, cryptography, sjcl

I am trying to build an application that stores user related information client side in localstorage. I am encrypting that data with a password given by user.

If I implement forgot password and generate a new password how can I get back my data that is encrypted on old password.

I am using sjcl for encrypting data. Is there any technique to encrypt data with 2 passwords??

What would be an ideal pattern for this scenario??

Answer (score 1):

The conventional approach for this is called "key escrow." Basically, it means giving a copy of the key to someone that you trust.

If you won't trust *anyone,* then key escrow is not for you. Your only option is to make sure that you don't lose the one-and-only key. And this is a fairly common approach too. Many products that advertise secure storage emphasize this point. As examples, see Bruce Schneier's password manager "PasswordSafe," and LaCie's security-focused DropBox alternative, "Wuala."

There are accepted methods for encrypting data so that it could be decrypted with any one of several passwords. But I don't see how this helps; if you can't remember one password, how will you remember two?

Any other approach that pretends to avoid key escrow but still provides a backdoor to access your data if you lose the key is not secure and no one should trust it.